# Cannot redirect to logout page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, spring-security

i have a logout link in the header of all pages, and i want when the user hits the logout link he's redirected to the `/j_spring_security_logout` url which in turns will fire the logout filter of spring security.

so here's what i did:

```
<h:commandLink action="logout?faces-redirect=true" value="Logout"/>
```

and the navigation rule:

```
<navigation-rule>       
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>logout</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/j_spring_security_logout</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

i am using JSF2 and i always use prettyfaces for navigation, but right now i have to use navigation rules, so i was wondering why above code doesn't work ?

when clicking the url it doesn't work, please advise how to fix that.

Comment: You can use [`logout-url` parameter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-logout-logout-url) directly in Spring Security without any JSF, if you use XML namespace configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<to-view-id>` has to be a valid JSF view ID such as `/page.xhtml`, not an arbitrary non-JSF URL path.

Just use a plain HTML link.

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout">Logout</a>
```

Comment: but i don't want in the url to appear j_spring_security_logout, i guess that i should use action method with external context redirection, what do you think ?

Comment: A redirect would also make it to appear in the URL.